# jQuery attr() not working on mobile Safari

Tags: jquery, html, safari, mobile-safari, client-side

Here's my HTML tag.

```
<a href="#" id="test"><img id="imgtest" src="imgs/test_0.png" width="108" height="32" /></a>
```

Here's my jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").click(function () {    
        $('#imgtest').attr('src', 'imgs/test.png');
    });
});
```

I need to change the image when the anchor tag is clicked.
This works perfectly on any browser on desktop but mobile Safari.
What's wrong with this?

Comment: Did you try changing the property with `prop` instead of `attr` ?

Comment: i'll try now, will let you know the result. thanks :)

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: changing attr to prop did not work :( i dont get any error message. i do not know how to get the error using my iPhone.

Comment: does it work if you touch it twice?

Answer (score 2):

**Mobile Safari** will only produce mouse events when the user taps on a clickable element, like a link. You can make an element clickable by adding an `onClick` event handler to it, even if that handler does nothing.

-- from [here](http://sitr.us/2011/07/28/how-mobile-safari-emulates-mouse-events.html)

Adding a dummy onclick handler to make an element clickable (that normally isn't):

```
<img id="imgtest" src="imgs/test_0.png" onclick="void(0)" />
```

You have already made it a link, so that isn't the problem.

---

However, if there is a `mouseover` event that changes any content (e.g. hiding/showing stuff, like in a dropdown menu) the click event won't fire.

[image: mouse hands]

-- from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html)

---

You could also try `touchstart` or `touchend` events.

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").on("click touchend", function () {    
        $('#imgtest').attr('src', 'imgs/test.png');
    });
});
```